# An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext, an error with fetch request

Tags: javascript, curl, oauth, fetch-api

I'm trying to call to an API endpoint using **cURL** and **fetch(JavaScript)**, as it works fine with cURL where it's equal fetch doesn't.

Here is the cURL request:

```
curl -i -L -H 'Accept: application/json' --data 'client_id=[ID]&c
lient_secret=[SECRET]&grant_type=authorization_code&red
irect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI]&code=[CODE]' https://orcid.org/oauth/token
```

Where fetch:

```
 fetch("https://orcid.org/oauth/token", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
        body: `client_id=[ID]&c
lient_secret=[SECRET]&grant_type=authorization_code&red
irect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI]&code=[CODE]`,
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

**ERROR:**

```
www-authenticate: Bearer realm="orcid", error="unauthorized", error_description="An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with PayU. My issue was gone once I changed stringified body to `URLSearchParams` object.

I'm not sure if it helps you but you could try the following code:

```
const headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
};

const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('client_id', ID);
params.append('client_secret', SECRET);
params.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
params.append('redirect_uri', REDIRECT_URI);
params.append('code', CODE);

fetch("https://orcid.org/oauth/token", {
  method: "POST",
  headers,
  body: params,
});
```